# How to input arrays of numbers in one line(not one input in each line) for a given number of n elements and make a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

N=5

Input: `12345`

Output: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: See [ask]. You need to show what you tried as a [mcve]. No one here wants to write this code for you. ("python parse a number into a list" makes a good web search if you really just want to copy a solution off the internet. But why not give it a try yourself?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `map` or `lambda`, you can just use the `list()` function or list comprehension;

```
an_array = input()
>>> 12345
print([int(x) for x in an_array])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through input string ([using For loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)) and create array ([using List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)).